# Is there proof that a reflected photon is the original photon before reflection?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reflection

I came accross the DIRAC-Ansatz in [On the Notation of MAXWELL’s Field Equations](http://www.hro-cigre.hr/downloads/12savjetovanje/E_&_M_Field_Variables-20_equations.pdf)  where it says

> Therefore as another consequence there must exist two different kinds of photons, which interact in different ways with matter . Also this has until today never been observed."

Never been observed? But what about [Longitudinal waves](http://crystalradioinitiative.com)?

> Tesla knew something else, which is not widely known and that is the fact that every AM station is simultaneously transmitting it's signal through the ground longitudinally - and that signalin does NOT diminish over distance in the same way. That means that receiving the longitudinal transmission allows you to have much more energy that can be used to power bulbs or other devices. This is a Tesla style Longitudinal transmission or dielectric/electrostatic transmission.

From what I have researched I wondered is there more than one photon? When light reflects, is that an answer of the matter which reflected the light with the same atributes? Or is it really the same photon?

Comment: The second link you gave is pure bullshit,don't trust anything it says. And you know if the reflected photon is the original one because photons are indistinguishable.

Comment: read in the second link : Eric shows how all electric phenomena can be mathematically measured and engineered WITHOUT using calculus or "Maxwell's Equations." ... I agree , it is b.s. but purity is a mythic notion

Comment: I agree that the second link is like an advertisement but what about longitudinal waves? Also please do be aware that Oliver Heaviside, Lorenz and others have significantly modified the original theories from Maxwell even after Maxwell himself changed his original theory.

Comment: Longitudinal waves could be associated to massive photons, but it is expected that photons are not massive. The experimental upper bound is really tiny.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the same photon but the same energy. After the electron absorbs the energy of a photon it later releases a new photon in a random direction.

Comment: why in a random direction ? what about energy and momentum conservations ?

Comment: Maybe in a synchrotron the direction can be predicted but other than that I believe photons are emitted in random directions. The energy transferred from a photon to an electron comes from its frequency. The excited electron then releases a new photo in a new  direction.

Comment: @ Bill Alsept : then how do explain the reflection properties ?

Comment: The properties of reflection do not apply to one single photon. It takes many as in the example  Feynman gives in QED

Comment: Think about it this way. If you and another person we're standing in front of a mirror each looking at The reflection of a light source from your own unique position. You would both see the reflection at a different point on the mirror. Now what if the light source emitted one photon at a time? Who would it go to? Most likely one single photon would miss either one of them and it definitely wouldn't go out to both of them at the same time. It would take billions coming from every point on the mirror to eventually make the image from each person's point of view

Comment: another counter example : how can you see through glasses ? it's not the main question but if you ask a new one about reflection ( without diffusion ) you will get a whole answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking/saying?